# RavenDb Return only indexed fields

Tags: .net, nosql, ravendb

Let's imagine I have the following index:

```
public class PostsForList: AbstractIndexCreationTask<Post, PostsForList.ReduceResult>
{
  public class ReduceResult
  {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public long CommentsCount { get; set; }
  }

  public PostsForList()
  {
    Map = posts => from post in posts
                   select
                     new
                     {
                       Id = post.Id,
                       Title = post.Title,
                       CommentsCount = post.Comments,
                     };
  }
}
```

If I execute it, RavenDb will return not only Id, Title and CommentsCount but the whole Post document. But I don't need the whole document (let's imagine it contains a lot of other stuff).

As I unserstand, there are two solutions now:

1. Mark index fields as Stored and call
   AsProjection for the query. I don't like
   this solution by performance and extra disk space consuming reasons.
   It's more like workaround than solution.
2. Convert Map index to MapReduce index by introduction of some fake Reduce part (equal to Map) which
       actually won't reduce anything. It looks like better solution but it
       is annoying to implement this fake Reduce part.

So why there is no more natural solution for that (or may be I just don't know about it)? Is it a conceptual solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Projections feature](http://old.ravendb.net/faq/projections) of RavenDB to do the conversion.

This just changes the shape of the Json doc after RavenDB has pulled it from the doc store, so the fields don't have to be marked as `Stored` for it to work

```
  public PostsForList()
  {
    Map = posts => from post in posts
                   select
                     new
                     {
                       Id = post.Id,
                       Title = post.Title,
                       CommentsCount = post.Comments,
                     };
    TransformResults =
        (database, posts) => from post in posts                                 
                                 select new { post.Id, post.Title, post.CommentsCount };
  }
```

You still need to us `.As<new type>` when you query this index, otherwise RavenDB will complain. Something like this:

```
session.Query<Post, PostTitleCommentsCount>()
   .Where(x => x.Title == "blah")
   .As<PostTitleCommentsCount>()
   .ToList();
```

It's most commonly used to allow joins, see [this blog post](http://ayende.com/blog/4661/ravendb-live-projections-or-how-to-do-joins-in-a-non-relational-database)  for more info, but works in this scenario as well.

Comment: As() will only change the shape of the output, AsProjection() will change the shape and pull the values out of the Lucene index (if they were indexed with `Stored = Yes`).